# Why do these rails/react on heroku compressed files seem to be increasing in number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, heroku, caching, compression

I have a web app and tried to compress the files using heroku-deflator. I am using a rails app. It appeared to be working but there seems to be more files I see as time goes on in the heroku push with something called gzip. It has taken time to notice it because it happened slowly. At least for a couple months. But I am absolutely sure this list is increasing. My website is hosted on heroku. The server is ruby on rails and the frontend is handled by a react project inside the ruby on rails project.

I've tried to mess with serving assets and messing with headers in rails production environment and application.rb and application_controller. I am a bootcamp coder so I have gaps in my knowledge and know something very rookie-level could be happening here. Relevant files attached starting with the list I am talking about that is inside git push heroku main. I also have code in the react project that possibly somehow is causing this but I really don't think it's related. But I will respond to supply extra files quickly! First attachment is heroku push from my command prompt.

[image: Command Prompt (git push heroku main)]

Top level package.json(root level, there is also one in the react client but I don't think it's needed for my question)

```
{
  "name": "heroku-deploy",
  "description": "Build scripts for Heroku",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.12.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf public",
    "build": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run deploy"
  }
}
```

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
gem "bcrypt"
# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"
# gem "rack-cors"
# gem 'sprockets-rails'
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
# gem 'bootsnap'
# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem "rack-cors", :require => 'rack/cors'
gem "memcachier"

gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'terser'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'heroku-deflater', :group => :production

gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end
```

config.ru(root level)

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require_relative "config/environment"
use Rack::Deflater
run Rails.application
Rails.application.load_server
```

Public folder index.html(98% sure is irrelevant for my question)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="preload" href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css"></noscript>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <!-- <link href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="preload" as="style"> -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <title>React App</title>
        <!-- <script
            async
            defer="defer"
            src="/static/js/main.80687440.js">
        </script> -->

        <!-- <noscript><link async href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript> 
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <link rel="preload" href="/static/js/main.80687440.js" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/main.80687440.js"></noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Config folder application.rb

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :develo pment, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MidlandOrtho
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
    config.api_only = true
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :lax
    # config.assets.enabled = true
    # config.serve_static_assets = true
  end
end
```

Config Folder environments production.rb

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  # config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
  # config.assets.compress = false
  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=31536000"
  }
  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  # config.assets.js_compressor :uglifier
  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000.com"
  config.asset_host = "http://assets.midland-ortho.herokuapp.com"
  
  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect" # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = "wss://example.com/cable"
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ "http://example.com", /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Include generic and useful information about system operation, but avoid logging too much
  # information to avoid inadvertent exposure of personally identifiable information (PII).
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :redis_store, "redis://midland-ortho.herokuapp.com/0/cache", { expires_in: 90.minutes }


  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "midland_ortho_production"


  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Don't log any deprecations.
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require "syslog/logger"
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new "app-name")

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

App folder controllers application_controller.rb(if you notice anything that is incredibly inexperienced in my files please inform! There is a lot I'm sure)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include ActionController::Cookies
    before_action :authenticate_user, :cors_preflight_check
    # before_action :set_cors_headers
    before_action :cors_set_access_control_headers

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :invalid_record
    after_action :cors_set_access_control_headers
    def cors_set_access_control_headers
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://midland-ortho.herokuapp.com' || 'http://locahost:3000'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '31536000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end

    # If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
    # request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
    # text/plain.
    def cors_preflight_check
      if request.method == :options
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://midland-ortho.herokuapp.com' || 'http://locahost:3000'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '31536000'
        render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
      end
    end
    private
    def set_cors_headers
            response.set_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin
    end

    def origin
            request.headers["Origin"] || "*"
    end
    def current_user
        # @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    end

    def record_not_found(errors)
        # render json: errors.message, status: :not_found
    end

    def invalid_record(invalid)
        # render json: invalid.record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

    def authenticate_user
        # puts "*" * 100
        # puts "authenticate_user debugging"
        # puts "current_user"
        # puts current_user
        # puts "current_user.inspect"
        # puts current_user.inspect
        # puts "*" * 100
        # render json: "Not authorized", status: :unauthorized unless current_user
    end
end
```

Comment: Is it caching and not deleting old cached files or something?

Comment: Those are react files, nothing to do with Rails. Take a look at the info in the link shown in the output: https://cra.link/deployment FWIW, nothing surprising about the number of files in a project increasing over time. (voting to close)

Comment: (btw, I voted to close because of the heavy Rails focus of the question, no problem if you want to edit this, but if I were you I'd ask a new question once you've investigated the react side of things)

Comment: Thanks! I look at stackoverflow constantly but have asked very few questions for this exact reason. I can't get them exaclty right. I will take a look at your suggestions and if I absolutely need to I will fix or ask it differently. @smathy I think you actually answered my question. It's not rail's compressing the files.

Comment: I see the link. And it makes sense I'm adding files through time. Kind of obvious and the this question is all good. Thanks! @smathy